# Updating list definition using features

Tags: list-definition, feature-upgrade

I have a feature that deploys content types, a list definition and template that uses these content types and finally a list instance. This feature is already in production.

Now we have a change request to add new views to this existing list. So I make the changes to schema.xml and upgrade the solution. But alas, the new views don't show up. If I create a new site, the list instance is created with the new views. I tried deactivating/reactivating, iisreset but still no success. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

Well you made changes to List Schema definition, changes will only be applied to New Instances of List not to existing one. You have to write additional Upgrader feature which will Add the view programatically.

You can also look into the http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/06/feature-upgrade-part-1-fundamentals.html (Upgrade Feature Concept in SP2010) .