# FeatureUpgrading - Providing an updated schema.xml file possible?

Tags: caml, feature-upgrade

I've read a lot now about the FeatureUpgrading method. But I'm still asking myself, if I could provide an updated list definition (schema.xml) file in the ElementManifests. There are new views in this updated schema.xml.

Or is this not the way to do it?

Here is my CAML code, I thought, I can use to update the schema.xml. But this code does not work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <UpgradeActions>
    <VersionRange BeginVersion="0.0.0.0" EndVersion="9.0.0.0">
      <ApplyElementManifests>
        <ElementManifest Location="DL_Definition_Products\Elements.xml" />
        <ElementFile Location="DL_Definition_Products\Schema.xml" />
      </ApplyElementManifests>
    </VersionRange>
  </UpgradeActions>
</Feature>
```

Has anybody a hint for me?

Comment: I found a similar post here [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28331/updating-list-definition-using-features?rq=1](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28331/updating-list-definition-using-features?rq=1). That post answers my question.